# Run mimetex cgi binary on nginx

Tags: php, nginx, cgi

I switched to Nginx (from Apache) and now try to run mimetext to produce math terms as gif files. But it seems nginx does not have a cgi-bin support.

Some recommend to run apache on different port but i don't want to use apache anymore. It uses up to much memory, i have a lightweight vserver only and with nginx everything runs fine.

Is there any other way to execute my mimetex cgi?

On apache i used a simple php script which then used PHP curl to call `http://localhost/cgi-bin/mimetex.cgi?[code]` which then saves the result in a file, which then is openend with "imagegif". So my `<img>` tags simply point to that php script. I would like to do the same using nginx. Is that possible. Seems to be a pain to run CGI stuff on nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Installed fcgiwrap on my debian OS, which started the daemon, then set up the location block to /cgi-bin, created that folder on my root, put mimetex.cgi i previously compiled on that server. DONE.